# Tsheets API update timesheet custom field c#

Tags: c#, json, api

I am trying to update a custom field which is a child jobject. This is where I am and the result.

```
string costCode= "DX Piping";

dynamic timesheet = new JObject();

timesheet.id = tsID;
timesheet.start = isoDate;

//Need to update custom field:247513 with the value in costcode should be another jobject?
timesheet.customfields["247513"] = costCode;

timesheet.end = isoDate;
```

This works in Postman.

```
   "data":
  [
    {
       "id": 45037255,
       "end": "2020-06-17T14:00:00-04:00",
       "start": "2020-06-17T12:00:00-04:00",
        "customfields": {
                    "247513": "DX Piping"
                }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is resulting in Error: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference.
Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Can you give us all the code, i dont think the probleme come from what you how us

Comment: The problem is the formatting of the custom field. Is this correct? The other code works fine without that line. Its a JObject() type. I will post more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this did the trick:

```
      timesheet.customfields = new JObject();
      timesheet.customfields.Add("247513", costCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
if(timesheet.customfields["247513"] != null){
   timesheet.customfields["247513"] = costCode;
}
else
{
   timesheet.customfields.add("247513",costCode);
}
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm

Comment: Same result, sorry.

Comment: If you log your costCode, what do you have ?

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: string costCode= "DX Piping";